# User authentication, roles and permissions

Tags: servicestack

In the AppHost module, I'm opening/creating an NHibernate based authentication repository (using the "ServiceStack.Authentication.NHibernate" module), and subsequently creating a default user:

HibernateFactory = RepoDatabaseFactory(typeof(ServiceStack.Authentication.NHibernate.UserAuthMap).Assembly);
      NHSession = HibernateFactory.OpenSession();
      container.Register(NHSession);
      NHibernateUserAuthRepository UserRepository = new NHibernateUserAuthRepository(HibernateFactory);
      container.Register(UserRepository);
      CurrentSessionContext.Bind(NHSession);

```
  var Authorization = UserRepository.GetUserAuthByUserName("miga");

  if (Authorization == null)
    {
    UserRepository.CreateUserAuth(
      new UserAuth
        {
        UserName = "miga",
        FirstName = "xxxxxx",
        LastName = "xxxxxx",
        Address = "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
        PostalCode = "xxxxxx",
        City = "xxxxxx",
        Country = "xxxxx",
        Gender = "xxxxx",
        PhoneNumber = "xxxxxx",
        Email = "xxxxxxx",
        Roles = new List<string> { RoleNames.Admin },
        Culture = "xxxxx"
        },
      "xxxxxx");
    }

  container.Register<ICacheClient>(new MemoryCacheClient());

  UserRepository.InitSchema();
```

where the RepoDatabaseFactory is:

```
public NHibernate.ISessionFactory RepoDatabaseFactory(Assembly AuthAssembly)
  {
  var Configuration = Fluently.Configure()
   .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2012.ConnectionString(ConnString).UseReflectionOptimizer()).Mappings(m =>
     {
       m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssembly(AuthAssembly);
     })
   .CurrentSessionContext("web")
   .BuildConfiguration();

  var Exporter = new SchemaExport(Configuration);
  Exporter.Execute(false, false, false);

  var SessionFactory = Configuration.BuildSessionFactory();

  return (SessionFactory);
  }
```

To a certain extent this works; i.e. the relevant tables are created ("UserAuth", "UserAuth_Permissions", "UserAuth_Roles", "UserOAuthProvider" and "UserOAuthProvider_Items"). When creating the user "miga" as above, you'll notice the line "Roles = new List { RoleNames.Admin }" in the "new UserAuth" statement. Subsequently, the user data above is in fact added to the "UserAuth" table, but the "Admin" role is *not* added to the "UserAuth_Roles" table as I would have expected. Inserting a new record in the "UserAuth_Roles" table manually (containing the user id of the "miga" user and the admin rolename - e.g. 1, "Admin") still - it appears - does not provide the "miga" user with an "Admin" role:

Using the following fragment:

```
  var Client = new RestClient("http://localhost:42147/");
  Client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator("miga", "xxxxxxxx");
  var Request = new RestRequest("assignroles", Method.POST);
  Request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
  Request.AddBody(new { UserName = "Sally", Roles = "Write" });
  var Response = Client.Post<AssignRoleResponse>(Request);
```

I get an authorization error with an "Invalid Role" message. So my question is basically how to get this working in an NHibernate context ?

Comment: Not sure if related but you seem to be calling `UserRepository.InitSchema();` after trying to create the user InitSchema tries to create auth tables so should be called first. Example from tests https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/0e202f2e949bd6fa187ad9276c006fb9ee4904ab/tests/ServiceStack.AuthWeb.Tests/AppHost.cs#L164-L189

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The InitSchema() method, however, has no impact on the problem - it can be commented out without any issues.

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!